# font style, underline inside italic makes the text out of margin

Tags: fonts

I want to have a smaller part of an `italic` text, underlined. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\textit{
Ham followed now ecstatic use speaking exercise may repeated. \underline{Himself he evident oh greatly my on inhabit general concern. It earnest amongst he showing females so improve in picture. Mrs can hundred its greater account.} Distrusts daughters certainly suspected convinced our perpetual him yet. Words did noise taken right state are since.}

\end{document}
```

However, it makes the text out of margin like the following:

[image]

How should I fix this?

Comment: Use something like package `ulem` or `soul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\begin{document}

\textit{
Ham followed now ecstatic use speaking exercise may repeated. \ul{Himself he evident oh greatly my on inhabit general concern. It earnest amongst he showing females so improve in picture. Mrs can hundred its greater account.} Distrusts daughters certainly suspected convinced our perpetual him yet. Words did noise taken right state are since.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Package `soulutf8` would be recommended  for utf8 encoding.